# AWS EC2 How to install Windows Updates and Reboot computer remotely?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, command-line-interface, windows-update

I want to run a command via AWS [Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-run-command-remote-instance-management-at-scale/) that downloads and installs windows updates on a remote Windows 2012 R2 Server instance running on EC2, and reboots the instance.

I tried suggestions on the following pages:

1. [How to install Windows Updates from command-line](https://serverfault.com/questions/10122/how-to-install-windows-updates-from-command-line/10190#10190)

Running `wuauclt.exe /detectnow` or `wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow` has no visible affect on Windows Server 2012.

2. [https://superuser.com/questions/462425/can-i-invoke-windows-update-from-the-
   command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/462425/can-i-invoke-windows-update-from-the-command-line)

Running `wusu update /forcerestart` does not work, but does produce an error screen saying that `<update>` needs to be a directory. However, I do not know where the updates to be installed reside.

3. [wusu offline updater](http://www.wsusoffline.net/docs/)

This tool seems to be focused on `offline` installation which is interesting, but doesn't seem applicable to me.

4. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/407498/automatically-install-all-windows-update-packages-and-reboot-machines-remotely) is for Windows Server 2008 and no one seems to be able to answer it.

I'm apparently not doing something right.

Comment: What are the Automatic Updates settings set to on the server?

Comment: Settings are set to "Download but do not install"

Answer (score 0):

There is no Microsoft's easy command to run a Windows Update at will.

I have created this new PowerShell tool that can be useful for installing Windows updates remotely , give it a try:

https://github.com/Aquiles1976/WUT

Comment: When you post identical answer to separate questions it feels like spam. If you're the author, please disclose so.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my answer now.